# Henstock–Kurzweil integral for unbounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: reference-request, integration

I am working through the textbook *Analyse : fondements, techniques, évolution* by Jean Mawhin (in French). It was published in 2002 and its main characteristic is to introduce integration to undergraduate students with the Henstock–Kurzweil/Denjoy-Perron integral. The exposition is quite general, dealing directly with functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$. Lebesgue integrable functions are defined as the integrable (in the sense of HK) ones that are also absolutely integrable.

The integral is first defined on $n$-cells of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then on bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Finally, the author deals with the integral defined on unbounded domains of $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, this last step is carried out only for Lebesgue-integrable functions. I quote from the Section 13.6:

"L’extension de la notion d’intégrale de Denjoy-Perron à des parties non bornées de $\mathbb{R}^n$ lorsque $n \geqslant 2$ est un problème délicat qui attend encore sa solution définitive. Nous nous contenterons dès lors de développer cette extension dans l’important cas particulier de la L-intégrabilité, [...]"

which approximately translates to

"Extending the notion of Denjoy-Perron integral to unbounded domains of $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n \geqslant 2$ is a delicate problem that is still waiting for a definitive solution. We will therefore simply present this extension in the important particular case of L[ebesgue]-integrability, [...]"

What is *delicate* about the gauge integral for unbounded domains of $\mathbb{R}^n$? And why is it not delicate for the Lebesgue integral? Furthermore, has a definite solution to this problem been found since then? I would also be happy to be redirected to the relevant literature.

Comment: This is just a guess: Since the HK-integral is not an absolute integral, one needs to find some canonical way to balance what one adds in terms of the positive and what one adds in terms of the negative part. It is not clear how one does this in higher dimensions. If the function is Lebesgue integrable, it is absolutely HK-integrable and the issue does not arise.